# How do i make my main image appear in the background of my masthead and button section

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I have tried to implement the following code but nothing happens

```
#masthead {
background: url('data05/mono/public_html/wp/wp- 
content/themes/spacious/images/monostaff1024x512.png') no-repeat center;
background-size: cover;  
}
```

I am having no luck. IS my file to path format incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

There is a space in your url after the "wp-"

```
data05/mono/public_html/wp/wp- 
content/themes/spacious/images/monostaff1024x512.png
```

Also the formatting seems off, see [background property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp).